# Css : two div's inside container div order

Tags: html, css, zooming, overlap

I have the following problem (please find img attached)
http://postimg.org/image/p6o5k07k9/

the yellow div is the container div and it should hold both the green div

(the table) and the red div (the buttons) the problem is that all the div's

are moving on zoom and starting to overlap.

any solution ? thank.

HTML :

```
<Div class="1" > 

<Div class="2" > </Div>
<Div class="3" > </Div>

</Div>
```

CSS :

.1{

```
margin-top: 100px;
margin-bottom: 100px;
background-color: yellow;
width: 80%;
```

}

.2{

```
float: right ;
background-color: green;
width: 75%
```

}

.3{

```
margin-left: 85px;
width: 20%;
background-color: red;
```

}

Comment: Hey Yuri, can you give us some code to work with please? It will make your question easier to answer.
Thanks! :)

Comment: Can you post complete HTML and CSS source or create a snippet on a CodePen or JSFiddle, so that we can see whole context?

Answer (score 0):

`div` become moveable when you put `float` property to it.
so `float:right;` is what that making the div move. now if you want to keep that green table div fix then add `position:fixed;` to its css and if you want to learn the positioning and layouts in `css3` refer some books and learn it all, do experiments and use dreamweaver cs4 or cs5 to explore `css` more and implement properties which you don't know, as it shows all the standard supported properties.